# Поддерживает ли request для Node.JS прокси IPv6?

Tags: node.js, request

В [репозитории](https://github.com/request/request) не нашел информации об этом. Обычные(IPv4) прокси точно поддерживаются.

Comment: Эээ? А какая разница? Прокси и ip это разные уровни сети

Comment: В смысле http пофиг что там ниже, хоть ipv4, хоть ipv6, хоть почтовые голуби

Comment: Т.е. можно указывать прокси в IPv6 формате заместо IPv4 и все будет работать точно так же?